# How to place multiple clickable images on top of a image that allows drag and pinch-zoom?

Tags: android

I have an image that illustrates a product. First of all this image needs to be touch-drag-able as well as pinch-zoom-able. My first thought would be to implement this with a `ImageView` and applying matrix transformation that is handled by the OnTouchListener/onTouch method (as described [here](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2/1747?tag=mantle_skin;content))

Now the tricky part is that I want to put additional images (map-style pin markers that point to a highlighted part of the product) on top of the illustration. These images must not scale, but obviously need to re-position with each drag or zoom. In addition these images need to be clickable (`ImageButtons`?).

1. Is `ImageView` + Matrix transformation the right approach in the given scenario?
2. What's the best way to include my pin-markers with the given requirements? (`ViewGroup`, `Canvas`, ... ?)